# Red or blue wire? 

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

There is a part where it asks in a side event to choose red or blue wire. Which one do I cut?

Comment: Like most things in this game, it's probably random :|

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is random. Both options actually trigger the exact same event (`ROCK_STARSHIP_MINE_DEFUSE2`), so it *really* doesn't matter which you choose.

The best resolution for this event is to use a beam drone to remove the bomb, costing you a drone part but still giving a low-level scrap reward. Another possibility is to use level 5 engines, which costs nothing but gives no reward.